# MySQL Select then update row in a view

Tags: mysql

I have tried to find this answer, but I can't seem to find what I am needing.

I am trying to select a row from a MySQL database, then update a counter in that row.  All of this needs to be done in a view so I can call it like a normal select.

I am working with an RSS feed where I have total access to MySQL,but zero access to the PHP that outputs the call (I didn't built it, but I inherited the problem :/).  To make the call work, I pass the table name into the RSS feed, and it pretty much does this:

```
SELECT * (table name I pass in).
```

Because I can't access the PHP, I can't add an update statement to mark the record I selected as used. All of this is so I don't display the same record twice until all the records have been selected.

I am hoping to be able to do this all in a view.  I would like to be able to select a row that hasn't been selected, then update that with a counter so I don't select it again.

Example:

```
SELECT title,counter FROM example WHERE counter = 0 UPDATE example SET counter++
```

Any help would be great!

EDIT: I need to be able to update the *same* row that I select.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do it in a server side script (like PHP)?

Comment: Yes. If I could do it in PHP I would in a heartbeat. Long story short, I have access to call a table, but not to edit the PHP.  Everything has to be done in MySQL

Comment: why you need the select and not simply perform the update ?

Comment: @scaisEdge I need to select row, pass it to PHP for an RSS feed, then update a counter.

Comment: I don't understand .. if you can explain with a clear sample what you need. i really better  and also tell us what kind of component you want use for perform this ..

Comment: @scaisEdge I updated the question with more info. Sorry it wasn't clear enough! Thank you for being cool about it.

Comment: If all you have access is to do a `select * from (table you pass)` consider in creating a function that returns a resultset so you can call it the same way and inside that function run your update code for the selected registries. I'm out of time now otherwise I would give you an answer on this. Someone else can do it here.